# Cycle through a randomly generated list of images

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to make a website based on the Bootstrap framework.

The homepage is to have a hero banner at the top that will cycle through perhaps 5 or 6 different images.

I'd like the site to randomly select these images from a folder of, say, 20 images so that each time the site is loaded a different sequence of images is displayed.

Can anyone suggest a way of achieving this?

Comment: you could start out by including the code that you have attempted.

Comment: Simple Use php for random generate HTML for images. Then use bootstrap carousel http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: You could use any of the many plugins that are already out there for this. RoyalSlider is a very good one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone. I think that I'll use JS as I'll mention below. @WimOmbelets I have not started writing any code as of yet, I was just wanting to get some suggestions on a good way to implement a solution.
So I'm thinking that I'll create a folder of images with filenames of the format "image_XX.jpg" where XX is a unique number from 1 and up. I'll then use JS to randomly generate 5 unique numbers between 1 and the number of images in the folder and then display the images associated with the randomly generated numbers. I will post my final code once done.
Thanks again :-)